# Solving a Congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question is How many integers n are there with 0<=n<=2014 and      21n=25 (mod29)? We have already found solutions to the equation 21x+29y=1       I am trying to multiply by 25 and take mod 29 but nothing seems to work. I am rather confused as 21 is a unit mod 29 so a unique solution exists immediately.

Answer (score 2):

$$29 = (21)+8$$
$$21 = 2(8)+5$$
$$8 = 5+3$$
$$5 = 3+2$$
$$3 = 2+1$$

Hence

\begin{align}
1 & = 3 - 2 \\
&=3 - (5-3) \\
& = 2(3)-5 \\
&= 2(8-5)-5 \\
&=2(8)-3(5) \\
&= 2(8)-3(21-2(8)) \\
&=8(8)-3(21) \\
&= 8(29-21)-3(21)\\
&= 8(29)-11(21)
\end{align}

Hence $$-11(21) \equiv 1 \mod 29$$

$$21n\equiv 25 \mod 29$$

$$n \equiv 25(-11) \equiv (-4)(-11) \equiv 15 \mod 29$$

$$2014 = 69(29) + 13$$

Since $13 < 15$, there are $69$ such solutions.